Is the given property preserved under weak$^*$ convergence?
Let $1 \le p < n$ and let $p^*$ be the Sobolev conjugate of $p$, i.e. $p^* = np/(n - p)$. Let $(\Omega_m)$ be an increasing sequence of bounded open sets such that $$ \lim_{m \to \infty} \sup \{r : B(0, r) \subset \Omega_m \} = \infty. $$ Assume $u_m \in W^{1, p}(\Omega_m)$, $0 \le u \le 1$ and $$ \lim_{m \to \infty} \frac{1}{|\Omega_m|} \int_{\Omega_m} |u_m|^{p^*} \, dx = 0, \quad \|\nabla u_m\|_{L^p(\Omega_m, \mathbb{R}^n)} \le C, $$
where $C$ does not depend on $m$. Since $(u_m)$ is uniformly bounded in $L^\infty(\mathbb{R}^n)$, we can assume without loss of generality that there exists $u \in \dot{W}^{1, p}(\mathbb{R}^n) \cap L^\infty(\mathbb{R}^n)$ such that $u_m \overset{\ast}\rightharpoonup u $ in $L^\infty(\mathbb{R}^n)$. Is it true that $$\lim_{m \to \infty} \frac{1}{|\Omega_m|} \int_{\Omega_m} |u|^{p^*} \, dx = 0 $$ as well?
EDIT: We actually have more than weak$^*$ convergence. By the Rellich-Kondrachov theorem and the uniform boundedness of $(u_m)$ in $L^\infty$, it is true that $u_m \to u$ in $L^q(K)$ for all compact $K$ and all $1 \le q < \infty$.

Here is another construction of a counterexample. Let $n=2$ and $p=1$, so that $p^*=2$.
Given $r>2$ define the following domain
$$
\Omega_r = B_r(0) \cup \left( B_{r^2}(0) \setminus \overline{B_{r+1}(0)} \right)
\cup \bigg( [0,r+1] \times (-1/r,+1/r) \bigg),
$$
which consists of the Ball $B_r(0)$ that is connected by a small bridge to the huge annulus $B_{r^2}(0) \setminus\overline{B_{r+1}(0)} $.
Define the function $v_r : \Omega_r \to \mathbb R$ by
$$
v_r(x) = \begin{cases} 
1 & \text{ if } |x| \le r\\
r+1-|x| & \text{ if } r \le |x| \le r+1\\
0 & \text{ otherwise }.
\end{cases}
$$
Then $v_r \in W^{1,\infty}(\Omega_r)$, $\|\nabla v_r\|_{L^1(\Omega_r)}$ is bounded for all $r$,
$\|v_r\|_{L^2(\Omega_r)}^2 =O(r^2)$, $|\Omega_r| =O(r^4)$.
Define the sequence $r_m$ by $r_m:=2^{(2^m)}$. Then $r_{m+1} = r_m^2$ and $\Omega_{r_m} \subset \Omega_{r_{m+1}}$. Set $u_m := v_{r_m}$.
This sequence satisfies all assumptions. However, $u_m \rightharpoonup^* 1$ in $L^\infty(\mathbb R^2)$.
I think that this construction can be generalized to arbitrary $n$ and $p$.

If the weak limit $u$ is in $W^{1,p}(\mathbb R^n)$ then the claim follows from Gagliardo-Nirenberg: there is $c>0$ such that
$$
\int_{\mathbb R^n} |u|^{p^*} \le c \|\nabla u\|_{L^p(\mathbb R^n)}^{ p^*},
$$
so that
$$
\frac1{|\Omega_m|} \int_{\Omega_m} |u|^{p^*}
\le
\frac1{|\Omega_m|} \int_{\mathbb R^n} |u|^{p^*}
\le 
c \frac1{|\Omega_m|}  \|\nabla u\|_{L^p(\mathbb R^n)}^{ p^*} \to 0,
$$
as the assumptions imply $|\Omega_m| \to \infty$.

The problem asks for $1 \le p < n$. In particular, $n \ge 2$. Also, the averages are computed for the $p^*$-th power, not $p$-th.

In that case the claim follows quickly from Gagliardo-Nirenberg inequality.

The inequality can't be applied since the functions do not vanish near the boundary. What do you mean exactly?

There is no boundary. The G-N inequality holds for functions from $W^{1,p}(\mathbb R^n)$, see, eg, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gagliardo%E2%80%93Nirenberg_interpolation_inequality

You wrote the inequality incorrectly. Also, the constant $c$ depends on the domain.

Which inequality? The domain is $\mathbb R^n$.

The functions are defined on bounded domains, not on $\mathbb{R}^n$. If you extend them to $\mathbb{R}^n$, then you get another term in the inequality involving the $L^p$-norm of the function on the bounded domain. Also, the constant in the inequality now depends on the bounded domain, so you can't simply pass to the limit.

Did you actually read the answer? I claim that the regularity $u \in W^{1,p}(\mathbb R^n)$ (which is taken from your question) already implies the desired convergence. I do not use the sequence $(u_m)$ in my answer at all.

Oh it's my bad. I am so sorry. There is a typo in my question. We do not know if the limit function is in $W^{1, p}(\mathbb{R}^n)$. It's derivative is $L^p$ integrable for sure but the function itself is only guaranteed to be in $L^\infty(\mathbb{R}^n)$. So I should have written $u \in \dot{W}^{1, p}(\mathbb{R}^n) \cap L^\infty(\mathbb{R}^n)$, i.e. $u$ is in the homogeneous Sobolev space.

I tried to construct another counterexample, please check.

Do you think there is a counterexample for arbitrary nested rectangles?
